# UML Activity Diagram question, is this correct way to display options for Main Menu?

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

Not sure if this is the correct way. Tried using the decision node but that only gives me options for two.
[image]

Comment: What tool do you use to have decision nodes limited to two outgoing edges ? Sorry to say but are  you sure you used a decision node ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it would be correct if you added guards to each of the outgoing control flows. This way the token emitted by `Main menu` would take an arbitrary route.

A decision is not limited to two outputs. However, if your tool only permits two you can make a cascade:

[image]